# Drivers for nvidia graphics card

Tags: drivers, nvidia

how can I install nvidia GM107M (gtx 960M)? I use inspiron 15 7566.

Logs from lshw:

```
stoton@stoton-Inspiron-7566:~$ sudo lshw -C video[sudo] hasło użytkownika stoton: 
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
   description: 3D controller
   product: GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a2
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:e2000000-e2ffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:e0000000-e1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:e3000000-e307ffff
*-display
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: HD Graphics 530
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 06
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:126 memory:e4000000-e4ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

@edit I use sudo apt-get instll nvidia-367

for now I have only this:

```
stoton@stoton-Inspiron-7566:~$ sudo lshw -C video
*-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: HD Graphics 530
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 06
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:126 memory:e4000000-e4ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

and my external monitor doesn't work :/

@edit2 after second restart I've got something like this:

```
stoton@stoton-Inspiron-7566:~$ sudo lshw -C video
*-display                 
   description: 3D controller
   product: GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a2
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
   resources: irq:130 memory:e2000000-e2ffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:e0000000-e1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:e3000000-e307ffff
   *-display
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: HD Graphics 530
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 06
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:126 memory:e4000000-e4ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

but external monitor still doesn't work

Comment: sudo apt install nvidia-367

Comment: my external monitro doesn't work :/ look my edit

Comment: `sudo apt install nvidia-367` and reboot.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: Secure boot in BIOS is disable

Comment: and still I can't see monitor in settings

Comment: When I reboot computer by moment my external monitor's working ... but after two second disable

Answer (score 0):

Try additional software. That's how I installed the drivers for my GeForce GT 635M.

Go to dash (super key by default) and type in 'additional drivers' and launch the additional drivers program. Once it loads, you should see that nvidia binary driver is available but not selected. Select it, and restart when prompted.

Comment: Ok I install my graphics card, but my external monitor still doesn't work..

Comment: @Kichiin At this point I have to doubt about you actually doing what has been suggested. In the comments above it was suggested to install a specific driver version but all your edits show `nouveau` being used and that usually means the proprietary driver hasn't been installed. If you really tried to use the commands in comments above and something for whatever reason isn't working there should be error messages. Where are they? You only mention reboots, did this did that not working...

Comment: I do  sudo apt install nvidia 367. But without result, i mean hdmi monitor still doesnt works